# c# DevExpress Grid Relation : How to make GridView show rows number?

Tags: c#, devexpress

How to display row number on Child/GrandChild's header following attach files below?

The code in above only work for gridView1_CustomDrawRowIndicator but it doesn't working for Child's CustomDrawRowIndicator event. And the result of using that code is row number begins with 0, how to make it begins with 1 like the result in this link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/835501/Master-Detail-Datagridview and https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215736/Master-Detail-Datagridview-in-Csharp

[Click Here to show the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4CX.png)
Here was the result that of the codes below:

```
    private void gridView1_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.Info.IsRowIndicator && e.RowHandle >= 0)
        {
            e.Info.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString();
            e.Info.Appearance.Font = new Font("CordiaUPC", 12);
            e.Info.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            e.Info.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            if (!indicatorIcon)
                e.Info.ImageIndex = -2;
        }
    }

    private void gridView2_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.Info.IsRowIndicator && e.RowHandle >= 0)
        {
            e.Info.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString();
            e.Info.Appearance.Font = new Font("CordiaUPC", 12);
            e.Info.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            e.Info.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            if (!indicatorIcon)
                e.Info.ImageIndex = -2;
        }
    }           

    private void gridView3_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.Info.IsRowIndicator && e.RowHandle >= 0)
        {
            e.Info.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString();
            e.Info.Appearance.Font = new Font("CordiaUPC", 12);
            e.Info.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            e.Info.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            if (!indicatorIcon)
                e.Info.ImageIndex = -2;
        }
    }
```

I tried this code but it was to add rows number on Columns But what I need is to show rows number on row header.

```
    private void gridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString();
    }
```

[Click here to show an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z0iL.png)

Comment: have you check this link https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2079/how-to-show-the-number-for-each-row-in-a-column-in-the-grid . To show correct row index use e.Info.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString() + 1;

Comment: Yes, but customdrawcell is to add more column for row number but what I wanted is to show row number on RowHeader.

Comment: I dont know how to show just row number on the header without adding unbound column. As for i know I have to add unbound column.

Comment: it's okay, thank you anyway

Comment: Use e.info.Display text. I found some similar solution from devexpress support. I have posted the code on Answer. Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this from this reference. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T126680/auto-row-number-in-grid

```
 gridView1.IndicatorWidth = 30;
        void gridView1_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.RowHandle >= 0 )
                e.Info.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: it's not working 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFrXz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Lio.png

Comment: Yes. your code looks good to me. It should work. I feel its related to some other property for the gridview. It is blocking from showing the header

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your code. The possiblities i can see from my side, it may be due to some properties or skin type you are using. Please debug line by line and see your customdrawrowindicator is executed and giving the expected result. Then check this link, it might help.  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q471358/customdrawrowindicator

Comment: I have design gridview to reproduce the issue. First grid showing number and child is not. If any success i will post.

Comment: because changing Text Header Columns on only GridView1 and on many GridViews, using code are different so I think I this case it also the same. the skin that I use is default.( public partial class Form_Customers_List : Form)

Comment: I am stuck with other work and i cant do test now. Meanwhile you can try with this video link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCOIG0IGWcM and this document https://tv.devexpress.com/Content/XtraGrid/XtraGridRowIndicators/XtraGridRowIndicators.docx

Comment: the codes that i putted in customdrawrowindicator event was came from that video. The doc. in the link said that it will be displayed only when is focused. My question is how to focus child row? by using gridview1 row expand event? thank you very much.